# HTML E-Mail gets surrounded by white space (just on mobile)

Tags: html, email, outlook, gmail, html-email

my HTML mails receive a white space around the actualy mail when viewed on mobile clients like the Outlook or GMail App.

As you can see here there is some white space on each side.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bt8y.png

In the McDonald's newsletter e.g. this white space isn't there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVrDh.jpg

I would like to know, how I can achieve it, that the white space disappears.

**Edit**

```
    <head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin:0;
        }

        #body {
            color: #848484;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 30px;
        }

        #body {
            color:#dd9f33;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 30px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
            #body {
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 25px;
                line-height: 40px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ededed">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table style="padding: 23px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                        <table style="border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff"
                               width="600">
                            <tr>
                                <td id="body" align="left" valign="top" style="">
                                    <div style="text-align: center;"><img width="600" src="some_image"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                        <table border="0" style="border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="15"
                               bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="600">
                            <tr>
                                <td id="body" align="left" valign="top">

                                    Here I have the plain Mail content, simple
                                    div tags

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                        <table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="15" width="100%" bgcolor="#ededed">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your email? It's hard to help as it is.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I have just included the current code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `border-collapse: collapse` to your tables, i.e.

```
<style type="text/css">
   table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
   }
</style>
```

Although really you should be inlining it for those email clients that don't accept `<style>` code, i.e.:

`<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">`

You can use an automated tool if it's in your `<style>` section to inline your code, such as https://inliner.cm/

Answer (score 0):

Border collapse doesn't change this. In order to prevent spaces on the sides of HTML e-mail in mobile devices you need to include body element in your markup and reset padding and margin properties.

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <!-- your HTML e-mail code here -->
</body>
```